# How to get JSONArrays without name in JSONObject

Tags: java, arrays, json, object

I want to get the three JSONArrays below with the help of each array's index 
My JSON:

```
 {
  [
    {
      "id": 3429,
      "name": "Mass Effect: Andromeda",
      "prix": 100,
      "description": "The newest Mass Effect instalement",
      "quantiteDisponible": 400,
      "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/igdb/image/upload/t_screenshot_big/xtn9vhiek0kdpetibmvw.webp"
    },
    {
      "id": 3430,
      "name": "Halo 5: Guardians",
      "prix": 10,
      "description": "Not the best Halo",
      "quantiteDisponible": 420,
      "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/igdb/image/upload/t_cover_big/rzjnrhuv5rozj52g9aq3.webp"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 3431,
      "name": "Bloodbonrne",
      "prix": 20,
      "description": "Better than you",
      "quantiteDisponible": 612,
      "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/igdb/image/upload/t_cover_big/fivw1ogfjw266t72kcn2.webp"
    },
    {
      "id": 3432,
      "name": "Dark Souls 3",
      "prix": 60,
      "description": "Prepare to die",
      "quantiteDisponible": 604,
      "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/igdb/image/upload/t_cover_big/ofu6ewg0tzdt5vmzcj9q.webp"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 3433,
      "name": "Mario Sunshine",
      "prix": 40,
      "description": "Mario Sunshine best Mario Game",
      "quantiteDisponible": 11,
      "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/igdb/image/upload/t_cover_big/ok5aq7j375uaxp59zr2g.webp"
    },
    {
      "id": 3434,
      "name": "Outlaw Golf",
      "prix": 60,
      "description": "Outlaw Golf is back with a bang!",
      "quantiteDisponible": 10,
      "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/igdb/image/upload/t_cover_big/cxgtamh2r6z7tezfs1og.webp"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know if it's possible and would greatly appreciate any  help
First I read the JSON store it into a variable:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(JsonText);
System.out.println(object.length());
```

The System.out.println returns 3, so it knows we're talking about the 3 JSON Arrays.

And this how I try and get the Arrays

```
for (int i = 0; i < object.length(); i++){
        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray(HELP);

}
```

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: have you tried using "0" (or "1" or "2") as the name? And why isn't the top-level a JSONArray already?

Comment: Is `{ [ ] } ` really valid JSON ?

Comment: I just want a dynamic json so in code i'll add a new category (a new console in this case). Like I already have Xbox, PS4 and Wii, and in my code I'll create 3DS and add it with the bunch as an array with its own jsonobjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this snippet

```
for (int i = 0; i < getArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject objects = getArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Iterator key = objects.keys();
        while (key.hasNext()) {
            String k = key.next().toString();
            System.out.println("Key : " + k + ", value : "
                    + objects.getString(k));
        }
        // System.out.println(objects.toString());
        System.out.println("-----------");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the value of i. But object.getJSONArray() accepts only string.So you can use like this.

```
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(JsonText);
    for(int i=0;i<obj.length();i++){

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray=obj.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(i));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```